# Remove seconds from the TIME function?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Okay so have a database that uses the time functions for a list of events and then displays the data as:

```
    echo "<b>Time Frame:";          
    echo "$time_start";  echo "&nbsp;-&nbsp;";    echo "$time_end";
```

Although that displays the time as 11:00:00 if i want the time to be 11:00 am. Is there anyway to make this time display as a standard "11:00"? and also if in the mysql datababse enter it as military time (ex. 13:00) to make it display 1:00pm?

I have tried many things. Please help.

http://pastebin.com/kaTZzGrx

Comment: your question is too vague.. Please be more specific adding as much code as possible so that we can understand your specific problem.

Comment: Sorry, just it's sometimes hard to put my questions in words. I guess, I'll upload code next time

Comment: Added code: http://pastebin.com/kaTZzGrx

Comment: are these MySQL time stamps?

Comment: Yes they are the TIME function

Comment: looks like you might also have the full timestamp stored as well? if so you could get rid of the extra columns and just use SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%H:%i') as start_time, DATE_FORMAT(date_end, '%H:%i') as end_time;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo date('G:i',strtotime($time_start)); //date('g:i a',strtotime($time_start));
or
$date = date_create($time_start);
echo date_format($date, 'G:i'); // echo date_format($date, 'g:i a');
or
$date = new DateTime($time_start);
echo $date->format('G:i'); // echo $date->format('g:i a');
```

Comment: But how to make it display the am/pm based on military time?

Comment: using this `date('h:i a',strtotime($time_start)); ` parameter `a` is used to display `am/pm`

Comment: Thanks, that works with the am/pm, but the millitary time stays at 13:00pm instead of 1:00pm. :/

Comment: for that use `H`, capital H return time format 0-23
for more information about date-time format - 
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: so lower case h would make it 1:00pm instead of 13:00? Because i only want military time in the database.

Comment: But how would i remove the 0 before the 1:00pm because it is currently putting spaces before the 1:00pm like so: 01:00pm

Comment: I mean i dont want a 0 before the times. It just doesn't look good. Like the time that I want displayed is 1:00pm but its displaying as: 01:00pm.

Comment: for that use `g/G` work same as `h/H` but remove leading zero

Comment: Thanks, that works :D. Yea now my code for displaying time looks like:         echo date('g:i a',strtotime($time_start)); echo"&nbsp;-&nbsp;"; echo date('g:i a',strtotime($time_end)); echo"<br>";

Comment: Just one quick thing? I noticed your good at code. Is there any way to get ahold of you if I need help in the future?

Comment: Why not let MySQL do the work and stop storing the time AND a timestamp when the timestamp already contains this info? check my answer below.

Comment: because the time is not a time that the data is inserted its for a "Upcoming events" website. But is there anyway to get ahold of you Pragnesh?

Comment: But don't you already have a date_start and date_end column which store a MySQL timestamp with the start and end date for the upcoming events?

Comment: just a natural assumption being that you are using "WHERE date_end >= CURDATE()"

Comment: The database has these coulumns id, title, date_start, date_stop, time_start, time_stop, image, hyperlink. Its hard to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**date()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [**strtotime()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions.

You can use this as below.

```
date('h:i a', strtotime($time));
```

Comment: but how to remove the 0 before the 09:00am or what ever?

Comment: this will not put `0` before `9:00`. Have a look at `date` function.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's built-in DateTime class will help here:

```
$time = new \DateTime("1:00:00");
echo $time->format("H:i");

// Output:
// 1:00
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

You can actually define your own format in both the constructor (to create the object) and the `format()` method (to print/display the object). Information about the supported formats is here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: But i dont think that would effect the times coming from my DataBase? Because it $time_start and $time_end? Maybe look at the pastebin? http://pastebin.com/kaTZzGrx

Comment: What is the data type of `date_start` and `date_end` in your database? Whatever they are, they should be parsed by PHP as strings. So as long as the format you're returning matches the format in your DateTime constructor, you'll be all set.

Comment: They are the function TIME. I entered the times in as military times.

Comment: If your values are stored as TIME in the database, then by default, they will be retrieved by PHP in a format like "00:00:00". Use the class I mentioned above, and then it's up to you to determine how you want to render it... That's what you'll use the `format()` method for.

Comment: I'm confused by the format, because I got this to work besides the 0 being displayed. http://pastebin.com/uNX6jpyj

Answer (score 1):

For removing seconds, you can use MYSQL or php approach:

MYSQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds), 1, 5);
```

PHP:

```
$cleantime=substr($time,0,5)
```

both will keep only hours and minutes

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your query..

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,date_start,date_end,DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%l:%i') as time_start, DATE_FORMAT(date_end, '%l:%i') as time_end,location,description,image,hyperlink FROM events3 WHERE date_end >= CURDATE() ORDER BY date_start LIMIT 5;");
```